# How to use inotifywait to watch for file rename in shell script

Tags: shell, inotifywait

I need to use inotifywait to watch for a folder.  Files come into that folder can be very large, that's why I use close_write and wait for the file to complete writing.  However, I also want an event to be triggered when a file is renamed under the same folder.  So what event should I watch for file rename?  I looked at the inotifywait manual page and I didn't find what I am looking for.  The inotify IN_MOVED_TO event seems the one I need but that's not inotifywait.

I also tried the moved_to, but first, it didn't trigger the event when file is renamed; second, if I have both close_write and moved_to, the moved_to might be triggered before close_write is triggered in case the file is very large.  Thanks.

```
 inotifywait --monitor --event close_write --format '%w%f %e %T' --timefmt '%F %T' $watchFolder 
   |  while read eventOutput
 do
    echo "eventOutput is:" $eventOutput
 done
```

Comment: Have you tried `MOVED_TO`?

Comment: I did.  But it didn't trigger the event.  Also, when there is no file rename, if the file is very large, the move_to might be triggered before the file completes writting.

Comment: _"I also tried the moved_to, but first, it didn't trigger the event when file is renamed;"_  I have never seen that happen.